# How to get current code row number in vbs?

Tags: vbscript

For example, I have a next code:

```
1. Dim a
2. Dim b
3. Dim c
4. Dim currentRow
5. a = 5
6. b = 9
7. c = a + b      
8. currentRow = ???   'There i need to get code row
9. MsgBox currentRow
```

So I need to get 8

Comment: Do you mean line number? Why? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Yes. I need to write line number in log.

Comment: If you are to quickly troubleshoot your script when cscript/wscript throws an error, just use a different text editor that show line numbers. Such as Notepad++.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The language does not provide this kind of introspection/reflection. So your options are:

1. Use a different kind of unique location identifier (Keyword, description, global counter)
2. Preprocess your .VBS files to insert/replace the current line number where needed
3. Execute your code in the Microsoft ScriptControl and make use of the .Line property of the Error object