# Displaying Line Number in VBSCript Error Handling

Tags: vbscript

Is it possible in VBScripting Error Handling to see the line number in the VBScript the error occurs?  For example, I can see the Error Number, the Description and the Source of the Error and display it in a message box, but is there a way to see the Line Number in my VBScript as well?

Comment: Related: [How to get current code row number in vbs?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18393995/3439404). Maybe [_2. Preprocess your `.VBS` files to insert/replace the current line number where needed_](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18394970/3439404) from the answer… `Err` object doesn't support such a property or method like `Err.Line`.

Comment: You probably want to know the step which the error occured on, rather than the line? Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29906239/2165759).